Interactive input EOF (End of File) waiting problem in lex and yacc
The below is my two files:
calc.l
%{
    #include "y.tab.h"
%}
%%
[0-9]+  { yylval = atoi(yytext); return NUMBER; }

[ \t\n ] ;
"+" { return '+'; }
"*" { return '*'; }
"(" { return '('; }
")" { return ')'; }
%%

int yywrap() {
    return 1;
}

calc.y
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int yylex(void);
void yyerror(const char *s);
%}

%token NUMBER
%left '+'
%left '*'

%%

/* Grammar rules and actions */
expr:
      expr '+' expr     { $$ = $1 + $3; }
    | expr '*' expr     { $$ = $1 * $3; }
    | '(' expr ')'      { $$ = $2; }
    | NUMBER            { $$ = $1; }
    ;

%%

void yyerror(const char *s){
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", s);
}

int main(void) {
    printf("Enter an expression: ");
    if(yyparse() == 0) {  
        printf("Valid.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

When I try to run them like below:
flex calc.l
bison -dy calc.y
gcc lex.yy.c y.tab.c
./a

Then, I input 3+3 and 'Enter'.
Enter an expression: 3+3
Then nothing happend. The program didn't exit.
Only when I press 'ctrl + z + enter', the expect answer "Valid." come out. I don't konw why. And how can I fix them to get the 'Valid' once I press enter key.

Since newlines are ignored by your lexer, an Enter won't do anything.  You need an actual EOF (from ctrlz or ctrld) to get an EOF.
You could change your lexer rules to have newline return EOF:
[\n]    return EOF;
[ \t]   ;  /* only ignore spaces and tabs */

